# Clicking a tokenized link for another contact leads to your activities being recorded as belonging to that user

Tags: webform-civicrm, tokens

This seems like a weird case that probably doesn't come up much, but it does seem to indicate something odd is happening.

If you are logged and click on a link for a Drupal webform with contact and hash tokens that are for another contact (for instance to test that link), then any activities you do in CiviCRM will be attached to that contact. So, if you create a group, it will say that other contact created the group or if you merge two contacts, it will say that other contact merged the contacts, etc.
This is fixed by logging out and back in again (and of course could be avoided by testing the link in an incognito window). Note that this does not require you to submit the webform, merely to load the webform page with the tokenized link.

I'm guessing this isn't something that is worth trying to track down, but thought I should put it here just in case.

Comment: I always use incognito to test a checksum as otherwise i would not be confident of my testing. i take you are saying 'i am logged in, i get a checksum link for another user and click that while logged in, then odd things happen'. if so i can only suggest to test checksums incognito or via another browser / 'people' (in the chrome sense)

Comment: Absolutely, that's what I would normally do (test in incognito), I just thought it was worth noting here as it doesn't seem like expected behaviour (that activities would be assigned to a different contact than the one that actually was logged in to perform them).

Comment: yep seems like something is clearly amiss - good reporting